# How to roll out a recoded website without losing traffic?

Tags: seo

I have a client whose website gets about 700 unique hits per day. However, there are a lot of problems with the site.

Among a list of improper coding techniques and xss vulnerabilities (that have been fixed), the biggest issue is the URLs are not SEO friendly at all. I believe a total overhaul of the site will put it in better health for the long run.

My fear is a new URL makeover will destroy any traffic coming from back links and cached by the search engines. I can do a 301 redirect via htaccess but this site has ~500 pages.

Comment: If you want to keep your backlinks, I don't see any other option than doing the 301 redirects.

Comment: 301s. I hope, at least, that some of these URLs follow a pattern, for your sake. Track down the amateur who wrote the original site and feed him with the old site's code printed on laminated paper.

Comment: @LiorCohen I just might do that :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using redirects is usually the preferred method.